# How can I add another string to stringbuilder?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have this part of code which I don't understand correctly. I know that it builds a string out of values from the database. I think it's only the `title`:

```
private String createSearchFieldContent(Report report) {
  return createSearchFieldContent(report.getTitle(), report.getDescription());
}

private String createSearchFieldContent(OverrideableStringValue title,
                                        OverrideableStringValue description) {

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(getValue(title));
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(getValue(description))) {
    builder.append(" ").append(getValue(description));
  }
  String searchTerm = StringUtils.replaceAll(builder.toString(), "\n", " ");
  return unaccent(searchTerm);
}
```

I have another value which I'd like to add to the `searchTerm`. It's stored in `report.getOwner()`. How is it possible that I can build a new `searchTerm` which includes the `title`, `description` and `owner`?

Thanks!

Comment: *I think it's only the title* - the `description` if not blank will also be appended.  Add a new parameter to your method and follow the same logic as for `description`

Comment: @ScaryWombat thx for clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
private String createSearchFieldContent(Report report) {
  return createSearchFieldContent(report.getTitle(), report.getDescription(), report.getOwner());
}

private String createSearchFieldContent(OverrideableStringValue title,
                                        OverrideableStringValue description, OverrideableStringValue owner) {

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(getValue(title));
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(getValue(description))) {
    builder.append(" ").append(getValue(description));
  }
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(getValue(owner))) {
    builder.append(" ").append(getValue(owner));
  }
  String searchTerm = StringUtils.replaceAll(builder.toString(), "\n", " ");
  return unaccent(searchTerm);
}
```

In the above code, we are passing the owner attribute to the `createSearchFieldContent` method like the other two, then the owner attribute is appended to string builder object just like description.

Comment: Thx, woks for me!

Comment: @bhanu Code only answers are frowned upon.  Please explain what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign new data to searchTerm:

```
searchTerm = StringUtils.replaceAll(builder.toString(), "\n", " ")
```

becomes

```
String part2 = "something you want to add"; 
searchTerm = searchTerm + part2;
```

Or you could use the StringBuilder to append new data to

```
builder.append("new data")
builder.append("newer data")
```

This gets added to the StringBuilder which is incorporated in the string value of searchTerm.

Comment: why not follow the same logic used for `description`?

Comment: That is also a good option, it depends on personal preference i guess. If there are NullPointerExceptions you should indeed check for value or nulls like they do in the description logic.